# What can I add to this food to make it taste good?

Tags: flavor, fish, boiling, seafood

I want to make some sprats + potatoes + some cheap vegetables like cabbage soup. What can I add to it to make it taste better? Some types of spices or some other cheap type of vegetables maybe? As long as it's cheap enough and makes it taste good, I'm fine with it.

Mainly the thing that I'm having a problem with is the fish taste, seeing as sprats taste kind of like herring, and boiled herring doesn't taste very good.

Pickled herring tastes great, so does salmon and other fish. Especially smoked. But not boiled sprats.

Note that I'm not looking for options like baking or frying the fish, I'm looking for a solution to the current problem, to **add** something, not to change something in this "recipe."

Comment: These sort of questions generally get closed as 'too vague' as there are people convinced that the only good question is one that only has one answer (which is rarely ever true).  You might want to try doing something like the ingredient search on All Recipes -- put in the ingredients you want to use, and see what it comes back with.  (although in this case, [I had to go with the more generic 'fish' rather than 'sprats' to get results](http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=soup&ingIncl=fish,potato&sort=re)).  It's possible that the solution is in preparation (ie, cooking method).

Comment: You might also try asking a question about how to reduce the fishy taste in sprats.  Even though that's doesn't fit the 'one true answer' concept, it's less likely to get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may get closed, but there are still some standard answers why broth doesn't taste good.

Number 1) salt, broth must have salt or some seasoning that gives the broth some character, otherwise no matter how else it may be good, it will taste dead and flat.

Number 2) there are certain triads of veg that need to form the basis of broths even if you use other ingredients in addition (like fish or chicken). Mirepoix is one of those, which is onion, carrot and celery. Another is the Cajun holy trinity of onion, peppers and celery, or the French duxelles of onions shallots and mushrooms. There is also the Portuguese refogado of onions, garlic and tomato.

Just a few days ago I made a ramen noodle soup that was cabbage based, but I still started with a mirepoix first, added cabbage and fish sauce, then after making the broth threw out all the spent veg, and tossed in fresh cabbage and mushrooms a few minutes before serving.

Make one of these the basis of your broth, and remember to salt "just enough" salt, not too
Much or too little. It requires tasting to get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It seems that I should at least add onion, as every possible option you named had onion in it. I do add salt, I have a good amount that I add, at least so far. It does help a lot, but not enough. I'll try onions and see what happens.

Comment: @Jack celery is in two of those foundations as well. Celery is huge in broth.

Comment: I could buy some celery greens, but root's too costly. I thought I'd substitute celery with cabbage when I was replying here.

Comment: Cabbage and celery are different. I don't use celery root, just stalks and leaves then they look good. That's where the good flavor is IMO. The white blanched parts I like to eat as I am cutting up the celery.

Comment: I will try that today!